# UITableViewCell subview disappears on selection(But the contents within this subview are visible)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

This is the .m file of my UITableViewCell.

```
#import "ContentCardTableViewCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ContentCardTableViewCell


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    if (highlighted) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        // Recover backgroundColor of subviews.
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        // Recover backgroundColor of subviews.
    }
}


@end
```

But one view in this UITableViewCell disappears on selection. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039366/views-disappearing-from-uitableviewcell-when-selected) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053340/why-do-all-backgrounds-disappear-on-uitableviewcell-select) and many more but nothing helped. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue.
If i set selectionStyle to ***UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone*** works fine, problem solved.
ie;

in the

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

add
   `[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];`

before returning the cell.Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to recover state after deselecting of cell

```
if (selected) {
    [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
// Recover backgroundColor of subviews.
}else{ 
    [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]
}
```

PS: it's preferred to setup color of cell.contentView